# Confused with loop and mutate vector in c++

Tags: c++, loops, vector, push-back

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

  vector<int> v{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

  for (auto it = v.begin(), e = v.end(); it != e; ++it) {
    const int x = *it;
    cout << x << endl;
    v.push_back(x);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I am new to c++, I have this program and I think the answer should be 0 1 2 3 4. But actually output is 0 0 2 3 4. I want to know the reason thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've invoked undefined behavior. The moment `v` resizes (which likely happens on the first `push_back`), all existing iterators are rendered invalid. You can't rely on any particular behavior in that case. The only reason you didn't end up with a semi-infinite loop is that you cached the `end` iterator too, and the two invalid iterators pointed to the old memory and kinda sorta worked as expected (but might not under a different compiler, OS, runtime library, phase of the moon, etc.).

Comment: I think it is because of the vector dynamically change its capacity. so the pointer is invalid in the edge.



```c++ 
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

  vector<int> v{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

  for (auto it = v.begin(), e = v.end(); it != e; ++it) {
    const int x = *it;
    cout << x << "," << v.capacity() << endl;
    v.push_back(x);
  }
  return 0;
}
```



0,11
0,22
2,22
3,22
4,22
5,22
6,22
7,22
8,22
9,22
10,22

Comment: @Xiongchenyu: Yes, the reason the iterators are invalidated is that, for efficiency, they're very thin wrappers around pointers to the underlying storage. When the underlying storage is reallocated, those pointers point to "dead" memory, so the iterators are invalid as well.